# iPhone SDK: How to generate a random time of day

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am having some problems trying to figure out the best way of generating a random time of day. For instance, if I want to choose a random time between the hours of 9am and 5pm, what would be the best way with the least amount of overhead on the device? I guess I need someone to point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its not iPhone specific, but generate a random number between 0 and 480 (# of minutes between 9AM and 5PM) and then add those minutes to 9AM.

Comment: The time ranges will vary. 9am-5pm is just an example. I want to be able to pick a random time between the hours that the user chooses.

Comment: Its the same answer then...figure out the number of minutes in the range, and then add it to your start time. I think you are making it more difficult than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the number of seconds between your start hour and your end hour, then use something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732247#2732469) to generate a random value between 0 and the number of seconds, then add that random number of seconds to the starting time.  Simple!  :)